# MVC Moving data form Table to Input

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

I'm trying to move data from a selected row in a table to a form in MVC. I'm using a jquery click event to retrieve the data from my table and move it to my form. The click event is working but it is moving the data to the wrong fields. Heres the click function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".innerTbltr").click(function () {
        alert("Event handle.");
        //this.css("background-color", "#E8EEF4");
        $("#firstName").val(this.childNodes[0].innerHTML);
        $("#lastName").val(this.childNodes[1].innerHTML);
        $("#address1").val(this.childNodes[2].innerHTML);
        $("#address2").val(this.childNodes[3].innerHTML);
        $("#city").val(this.childNodes[4].innerHTML);
        $("#state").val(this.childNodes[5].innerHTML);
        $("#zip").val(this.childNodes[6].innerHTML);
        $("#birthDate").val(this.childNodes[7].innerHTML);
    });
});
```

The form  is set up like this:

```
<form>
  <input id="firstName" type="text"/>
  <input id="lastName" type="text"/>
  <input id="address1" type="text"/>
  <input id="address2" type="text"/>
  <input id="city" type="text"/>
  <input id="state" type="text"/>
  <input id="zip" type="text"/>
  <input id="birthDate" type="text"/>
</form>
```

Currently the first name is put into the last name field. The last name is put into the address 1 field. The address 1 is put into the state field and the remaining two fields are left blank. As well as the fields in between the fields that have data are blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that not all the DOM is loaded Try putting the click event in a jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
//the click event here 
});
```

Comment: I tried jquery but nothing is happening. I've tried using jquery once before on this project with the same results. My javascript will execute but if I try jquery nothing happens.

Comment: Have yu included the jQuery.js ?

Comment: Yes visual studio includes the jquery library with the project.

Comment: Update: I put an alert into my jquery and after rebuilding the solution a couple of times the alert is running but the rest of the function doesn't seem to run. Also I received an error on the next line of code: `this.css("background-color","blue")` Error is This HTML Element has no method 'css'

Comment: Solution: Used jquery to make sure DOM was completely loaded. Adjusted childNode[] indexes to match text nodes in node list.